# assigning bounds to individual independent points within the scipy.optimize.curve_fit function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a Planck curve to radiance readings. I know the radiance at some known wavelengths (11 data points), the parameter to fit is the temperature.

The Planck function that returns the radiance from the wavelength and the temperature:

```
def bbody(lam, T) :
    lam = 1e-6 * lam # from micrometres to metres
    return 2*h*c**2 / ( lam**5 * ( np.exp(h*c/(lam*k*T)) - 1 ) ) # radiance in SI units: W.m-2.sr-1.m-1
```

is used by the scipy.optimize.curve_fit, with the input of the radiance readings at 11 wavelengths:

```
def fit_planck_curve(wavs_list, rads_list) :
    temp = curve_fit(bbody, wavs_list, rads_list, p0=1800)
    return(temp)
```

The fitting function is called after getting the radiance data and declaring the wavelengths at which they were made. Here an example:

```
wavelengths_list = [0.555, 0.659, 0.865, 1.375, 1.61, 2.25, 3.74, 10.85, 12, 3.74, 10.85]
radiances_list = [268900000.00000006, 233200000.00000003, 174400000.0, 200000.0, 49200000.0, 8800000.0, 725170.86180638766, 5713946.0379738025, 5468427.1473144693, 902723.66658727441, 5698079.1655633291]
Temp_estimate = fit_planck_curve(wavelengths_list, radiances_list)[0][0]
```

So far, this works.

But I would like to input some more information, namely the bounds for the wavelengths.
For each of the 11 wavelengths at which the radiance readings were made (independent variable), there are bounds:

```
wl_width_array = np.array([0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.015, 0.06, 0.05, 0.38, 0.9, 1, 0.38, 0.9])
wl_lowerbound_list = list(np.array(wavelengths_list) - wl_width_array)
wl_upperbound_list = list(np.array(wavelengths_list) + wl_width_array)
```

These two lists are the upper and lower bound for each of the 11 wavelengths.

How can I make scipy.optimize.curve_fit take into consideration these bounds? There is the bounds option, but from the examples, I understand that these are bounds on the independent variables as a whole, and not for individual points.

I tried to set the bounds to a 2-tuple, where the first element is the lower bounds for the two independent variables, and the second element is the upper bounds. Each element is made up of a list (the lower or upper bounds for the 11 wavelengths) and np.inf for the other independent variable, the temperature, so that that independent variable is not set to bounds):

```
wl_bounds = ([wl_lowerbound_list, -np.inf] , [wl_upperbound_list, np.inf])
```

However, I got an error.

How can this be done? Is this possible at all with scipy.optimize.curve_fit? or with an alternative?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your "bounds" somehow quantify uncertainties of the readings of the independent variable (wavelengths).

`bounds` parameter is definitely not helpful: it's job is to set the allowed bounds for the parameter you're estimating (e.g., you know that the temperature is not negative).

If you were dealing with errorbars on the dependent variable, you could use `least_squares` directly with the cost function of the form `sum_i (y_i - f(x_i))**2 / dy_i**2`.

Now since you're dealing with errorbars on an independent variable, that alone won't work. 
A simple way of taking those into account could be to assume some distribution for the individual measurements (e.g., a gaussian with the width given by your bounds), generate a bunch of synthetic datasets, fit those and analyze the resulting distribution of the temperature.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply. It's, as I feared, more complicated than I thought.